# Setup an Ruby Enviroment on a Windows Machine for Browser UI testing on Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby, selenium, cygwin, rake, ui-testing

Ultimate Ruby Challenge of my Life

Guys, first I~ll describe the enviroment.
I've ports 80, 443, 8080 (and all the obvious closed)
Firewall blocked many sites including all most common CDN's (amazon etc..)
And blocking all content sharing sites (dropbox, etc)

For this I am using my 3G, plugued on the computer, so I can download stuff up to 30mb.

Then I am in a Closed intranet, and I want to setup an ruby enviroment for intranet sites testing.

I had a few days strugling with NTLM but we are friends now, if I pass the login on the request like this http://user:password@domain.com/ it works (finally).

So currently I am at this stage, I planned to use Selenium for the scripts, since it supports many browsers and languages, but I can't get it to work on Cygwin, it shows FFI library installation errors, following FFI support on github page (means, build it yourself) I get stuck at this:

```
$ rake gem:install
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rubygems/tasks
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/tmp/ffi/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Ok, questions are:

There is any easier way of getting this done without virtual machines ? (this is my backup plan)
There is a way for to check if my ruby enviroment is properly installed under cygwin ? (Maybe this is the problem here)
I've seen people advsing to install RVM under cygwin so it can manage gem stuff for me ? (does this proceeds ?) 
Last but not least, do you have a suggestion to do this in an easier way using other technologies ? (I am open to Java, Python, Sikuli, etc...)

The final product would be a set of scripts that test and automate repetitive tasks under intranet enviroment, and they will be triggered by and PHP application that will call them after a button click.
(e.g. "Add user to application with role Admin" will trigger a script that knows how to handle that and perform the operation automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to use Cygwin? You should be able to do all ruby/selenium related things in windows, you may be over-complicating the problem by trying to use cygwin.

Why do you want to use selenium to automate repetitive tasks? Selenium is a web browser driver and it can do that, but a requests library to do required gets and posts would be faster and easier to maintain. From your question I'm confused if this is for UI testing purposes or if you are trying to automate one of your functions.

Comment: I was using cygwin because it is easier to use than windows cmd, it has package-control and other tools I am used to.

Using windows only is better ?

Actually my station will be used for intranet applications testing and ALSO to automate daily repetitive tasks like granting access to users on legacy systems and sometimes using them, because people don't know how.

Basically this is it.
Requests library you mean, https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty ?

Comment: If you're running a windows machine, I would avoid cygwin for anything important and I wouldn't spend too much time trying to troubleshoot it.